# PHP post action not running?

Tags: php, post

For some reason my post script in PHP is not running.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitEdit']))
{

}
?>
```

The contents are irrelevant as I have tested doing an echo right at the top and it does not work, outside of the isset I also tested an echo and it did work. Probably a really noob mistake but it matches the markup's name.

```
<form action="" id="form_lookup" method="POST">
    <input name="appointment_id" id="appointmentID" type="text" style="width: 30%;" placeholder="  Appointment ID"/>
    <input type="submit" id="btn_lookup" name="submitEdit" value="Lookup" style="width: 15%;"/>
</form>
```

Comment: is the `action` correct? Does the form page submit to itself?

Comment: Yes it should submit to the PHP at the top of the same page.

Comment: Which I should mention contains the first segment of PHP

Comment: have you tried a var_dump of $_POST and ... heck... $_REQUEST?

Comment: Do you have any redirects above this part?

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but are you running the script through a server (ie XAMPP)?

Comment: LUKE your code is working perfectly in local xampp and wamp sever.... just echo it and check.... like `if (isset($_POST['submitEdit']))
{
echo "success";
}`

Answer (score 0):

***Note: You must give name for the form. eg. name='test'***

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitEdit'])) {
   echo "Success";
}
?>

<form action="" name="form_lookup" id="form_lookup" method="POST">
    <input name="appointment_id" id="appointmentID" type="text" style="width: 30%;" placeholder="Appointment ID"/>
    <input type="submit" id="btn_lookup" name="submitEdit" value="Lookup" style="width: 15%;"/>
</form>
```

Now it will work perfectly....